# Limit length of characters in a regular expression

Tags: regex

Is there a way to limit a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to 100 characters *with* a regular expression?

```
\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size]
```

So `Look at me!` wouldn't work.

I want to limit the numbers, only allow numbers between 1 and 100.

Comment: What part are you trying to limit? The argument to `size` must be no greater than 100? The string between the tags must not be longer than 100? Or the entire match?

Comment: What I think he's trying to do is look up the maximum size from the `size=...` value, then use that in a regular expression to limit the length of the part matched. That usually isn't possible in a single pass.

Comment: This question is poorly explained and is Unclear.

Comment: See also universal solution via lookahead: [Restricting Character length in Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477182/restricting-character-length-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit a regex to 100 characters WITH regex?

Your example suggests that you'd like to grab a number from inside the regex and then use this number to place a maximum length on another part that is matched later in the regex. This usually isn't possible in a single pass. Your best bet is to have two separate regular expressions:

- one to match the maximum length you'd like to use
- one which uses the previously extracted value to verify that its own match does not exceed the specified length

If you just want to limit the number of characters matched by an expression, most regular expressions support *bounds* by using braces. For instance,

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

will match (US) phone numbers: exactly three digits, then a hyphen, then exactly three digits, then another hyphen, then exactly four digits.

Likewise, you can set upper or lower limits:

```
\d{5,10}
```

means "at least 5, but not more than 10 digits".

---

**Update:** The OP clarified that he's trying to limit the *value*, not the *length*. My new answer is **don't use regular expressions for that**. Extract the value, then compare it against the maximum you extracted from the size parameter. It's much less error-prone.

Comment: thanks and would anyone mind telling me, as im a complete noob, where in my regex i should put this? i tried `'/\[size=(.*?)\d{1,100}](.*?)\[\/size]/i'`

Comment: @Jorm: I'm not sure that your comment really solves the problem - this would allow a sequence of digits between 1 and 100 digits long, not values in the range "1" to "100".

Comment: @Jorm: Don't use regular expressions to validate numeric ranges. It's too error-prone. (See above.) Instead just extract the value from `size` with the first regex, then check to see if the second regex's extracted value violates the `size` parameter.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to restrict valid input to integer values between 1 and 100, this will do it:

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. **^** = start of input
2. **()** = multiple options to match
3. **First argument [1-9]** - matches any entries between 1 and 9
4. **|** = OR argument separator
5. **Second Argument [1-9][0-9]** - matches entries between 10 and 99
6. **Last Argument 100** - Self explanatory - matches entries of 100

This ***will not accept***:

1. Zero - 0
2. Any integer preceded with a zero - 01, 021, 001
3. Any integer greater than 100

Answer (score 9):

If you want numbers from 1 up to 100:

```
100|[1-9]\d?
```

Answer (score 4):

Limit the length of characters in a regular expression:

```
^[a-z]{6,15}$'
```

Limit length of characters or numbers in a regular expression:

```
^[a-z | 0-9]{6,15}$'
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>If you are using PCRE2, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889546) which makes use of non-atomic lookaheads.</sub>

## Is it possible to limit the maximum length?

If you are using .NET, then... **yes**, it is possible with balancing groups.

For example, let's say we want to match all instances of `\[size=(.*?)](.*?)\[/size]` in the following paragraph (generated by ChatGPT), where the total length, including those [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) tags, does not exceed 40. Those instances are marked in bold and italic for you to see:

> `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum velit a felis commodo, ac efficitur nunc [size=27]Hello World[/size] dictum. Fusce auctor, [size=30]This is a test[/size] sit amet hendrerit commodo, [size=59]The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog[/size] enim augue consectetur nulla, vel blandit magna est vel sapien. Nam [size=42]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[/size] mattis ligula eu [size=41]Happiness is a warm puppy[/size] condimentum rhoncus. [size=21]Short[/size] Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec interdum, [size=50]Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious[/size] ut posuere sapien venenatis vel.`

We will come back to this in a while.

## The idea behind this answer

A capturing group (`(?<group>)`) in .NET is basically a counter. We decrease that counter with a balancing group (`(?<-group>)`, note the `-`). This counter cannot be negative; we can't decrease it more than the number of stacks it has. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/21305238).

The main idea is to count our way to the given maximum length before decreasing that count until it reaches 0. That being said, this is another way to write `^.{40}`:

```
^
(?<counter>){40}
(?<-counter>.)+
```

`+` is supposed to match as many as there are to match. However, since `counter` has only 40 stacks, `+` is prevented from matching the 41st character. You are right, this is a silly example. However, we can take a step further.

## How to apply that idea to our example

As you can see, the regex `\[size=(.*?)](.*?)\[/size]` has some *concrete* parts and some *dynamic* parts. Needless to say, the maximum length of the dynamic parts is equals to the maximum length overall minus the concrete length.

Let L<sub>c</sub>, L<sub>d</sub> and L<sub>x</sub> be the length of the **c**oncrete parts, the **d**ynamic parts and the ma**x**imum length overall, correspondingly, this is the relationship between them in terms of inequations:

> L<sub>c</sub> + L<sub>d</sub> <= L<sub>x</sub>

> L<sub>d</sub> <= L<sub>x</sub> - L<sub>c</sub>

We know what L<sub>x</sub> is: 40. We also know what L<sub>c</sub> is: The length of `[size=][/size]`, or 14. This means L<sub>d</sub> is smaller than or equal to 40 - 14 = 26. In regex terms, that goes as follows:

```
(?<counter>){26}             # Push 26 stacks onto <counter>
\[size=((?<-counter>.)*?)]   # pop n stacks,
((?<-counter>.)*?)           # then another m.
\[/size]                     #
```

Since the number of stacks cannot be negative, *m* + *n* can never exceed 26.

Do note that whatever lies inbetween `=` and `]` is meaningless to regex itself. `[size=99]` is no different than `[size=10]`, regardless of what follows `]`.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/buLU38/1).

## Is there a way to limit the minimum length as well?

Obviously, **yes**. It wouldn't make sense to have the mi**n**imum length smaller than that of concrete parts, so let's just assume L<sub>n</sub> = 24. This means L<sub>d</sub> >= L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>c</sub> = 24 - 14 = 10.

We go the same way: Count first, decrease later. As with L<sub>m</sub>, if there are not enough stacks to be popped, the regex simply fails.

```
(?<max>){26}                 #
\[size=((?<min-max>.)*?)]    # Push a stack to <min>
((?<min-max>.)*?)            # whenever we pop a stack from <max>.
\[/size]                     #
(?<-min>){10}                # Finally, pop 10 stacks from <min>.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/buLU38/3).

## How widely applicable is this trick?

It relies on three simple things: the concrete parts, the dynamic parts as well as how good you are at counting, additions and substractions. The steps can be generically described as:

1. Set the counter to L<sub>x</sub> - L<sub>c</sub>, then
2. Apply `(?<-counter>)` to any single-character dynamic expression, including but not limited to character classes (`[]`), metasequences (e.g. `\d`, `\w`, etc.) and the almighty dot (`.`).

If there are branches, follow those steps separately for each branch:

```
(?<counter>){20}
(?:
  (?<-counter>){3}foo
  (?<-counter>.)+          # Maximum 17 characters
|
  (?<-counter>){4}baar
  (?<-counter>.)+          # Maximum 10 characters
  (?<-counter>){6}bazqux
)
```

Of course, you can also add new stacks to the counter should the need arises:

```
(?<counter>){20}
(?:
  (?<-counter>){3}foo
  (?<-counter>.)+
|
  (?<counter>){10}         # For some inexplicable reasons, add 10 to the limit.
  (?<-counter>){6}baar     # ...and, in the same spirit, 'baar' counts as -6.
  (?<-counter>.)+
  (?<-counter>){6}bazqux
)
```

Pretty powerful, isn't it? However...

## Is this worth it?

**No**. Unless you don't have access to a programming language, you should *not* use this trick in your (production) code. It is better to match all instances and then filter those you don't want out based on their length. Simplicity counts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a negative lookahead for the number of characters you want. So if you have a complex regex to get a specific format and you wanted to limit it to say, 50 characters. Then you could preface it with:

```
(?!.{51})
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is a sequel to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76822352) that makes use of .NET's balancing groups.</sub>

## I'm using PCRE2. Is there a way?

Well... **also yes**. I just discovered yet another beautiful (or horrible) PCRE2 feature: **Non-atomic lookaround assertions**.

## Fancy! What are those?

That's a great question! Thanks for asking! <sub>(Although even if you didn't, I'll just pretend that you did.)</sub>

Non-atomic lookarounds are essentially lookarounds, but they allow backtracking, unlike normal lookarounds which are [atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14412277) by default.

In a dialect of regex math that I just invented, the relationships between them can be represented by the following equations:

- `(?*)` = `(?=)` - `(?>)`
- `(?<*)` = `(?<=)` - `(?>)`

## Could you give some examples?

Of course! Here's a simple task:

> Given the following string, match every (non-overlapping) substring that:
>
> - Starts and ends with `@`
> - As long as possible, yet must not longer than 18 characters, and
> - The number of `-` between them must not exceed 10
>
> `@@--@---@@-@-@----@--@-@---@-@@-@-@-@@-@-@-@----@-@-@-@-@-@-@-@--@-@-@-@---@-@@-@--@--@--@----@`
>
> The expected result would be:
>
> `[@@--@---@@-@-@]----[@--@-@---@-@@-@-@]-[@@-@-@-@----@-@-@]-[@-@-@-@-@--@-@-@-@]---[@-@@-@--@--@--@]----@`

If we were to use .NET, we can easily work out something like this from what we learnt in the previous answer:

```
(?<w>){16}
(?<h>){10}
@(?<-w>@|(?<-h>-))+@
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8itIMJ/1).

### Applying what we (presumably) already knew

First, we want something that starts with `@` and ends with `@`. If we were to verify if a full string match our requirements or not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32477224) has told us that we can use a lookahead preceding to the actual expression to ensure its total length. The following matches `@@--@---@@-@-@` but not `@--@-@---@-@@-@-@-@@`:

```
(?=.{2,18}$)
^@(?:@*-){0,10}@*@$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0LUvoq/1).

That said, we can also swap the two expressions:

```
(?=@(?:@*-){0,10}@*@$)
^.{2,18}$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0LUvoq/2).

We were using `$` as an anchor to apply both expressions to the same piece of text. However, we can't use it in our original use case. Instead, we need to create our own anchor by adding a backreference:

```
(?=                   # Keep the current position in mind, skip forward to
  @(?:@*-){0,10}@*@   # the rightmost '@' that is at most 10 hyphens away
                      # from the current one (the one following this)
  (.*)                # and capture anything following it (until the end).
)                     # Back to current,
.{2,18}               # then match the following 2 to 18 chars iff
(?=\1$)               # they are themself followed by what we captured in group 1.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5j0XHU/1).

This matches:

> `[@@--@---@@-@-@]----@--@-@---[@-@@-@-@-@@-@-@-@]----@-@-@-[@-@-@-@-@--@-@-@-@]---[@-@@-@--@--@--@]----@`

Finally some results! However, the matches are not the same as what we expected. The engine skipped three `@` before finding the second match. Why?

### How the engine works under the hood

The first match is correct, so let's proceed to the `@` nearest to it:

```
...----@--@-@---@-@@-@-@-@@-@-@-@---...
       ^
```

The lookahead then advances to:

```
       1  2 3   4 56 7 8 9
...----@--@-@---@-@@-@-@-@@-@-@-@---...
                          ^<group 1...>
```

It did its job well: the expression inside it matched, everything following the 10th `@` is captured into group 1. However, it's the second expression (`.{2,18}`) that didn't match this 20-character substring:

```
       1  2 3   4 56 7 8 9
...----@--@-@---@-@@-@-@-@@-@-@-@---...
       [     20 chars     ]<group 1...>
```

This caused the whole match to fail, and the engine continued to the 2nd `@` instead of returning to the lookahead to backtrack to the 9th `@`. We don't want that. Luckily, this is precisely what a non-atomic lookahead is for:

```
(?*
  @(?:@*-){0,10}@*@
  (.*)
)
.{2,18}(?=\1$)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5j0XHU/2).

What's the difference between this one and the previous? Very subtle: `(?*)` instead of `(?=)`. This time, the engine backtracks to the 9th, and then the 8th, where it finally finds a match. The rest of the matches are also found this way.

## How widely applicable is this trick?

It follows this pattern:

- A non-atomic lookahead containing a backtrack-able expression and a capturing group
- Then one or more lookaheads, each contains an arbitrary expression followed by a backreference and `$`/`\z` or similar.
- Finally, the main expression and another lookahead to assert the anchor.

Do note that you need to be careful when choosing the first expression. For example, the following matches in ~98k steps against the problem I gave in my last answer:

```
(?*\[size=\d+].*?\[/size](.*))
(?=.{24,40}\1$)
.{0,39}t.*?(?=\1$)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/buLU38/4).

...whereas this one, albeit look very similar, can't even reach the same conclusion:

```
(?*.{24,40}(.*))
(?=\[size=\d+].*?\[/size]\1$)
.{0,39}t.*?(?=\1$)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/buLU38/6).

(Due to the nature of the text, `(?*)` can be replaced with `(?=)` for much better performance: [~3k steps](https://regex101.com/r/buLU38/7).)

## Is this worth it?

A much stronger **no**. This trick is even worse than the .NET one since you will also need to test your regex extensively to make sure that you chose a good first expression.

Knowing about these tricks is a good thing, using them in production code is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^(\d{2})|^(\d{4})|^(\d{5}))$
```

This expression takes the number of length 2,4 and 5. Valid Inputs are 
12
1234
12345