# How to match an odd number of any character in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a purely Regex solution to get odd length substring made up of similar characters.

For example, my string:

```
hjasaaasjasjbbbbbashjasccccccc
```

So, the resulting matches should be:

```
[aaa],[bbbbb],[ccccccc]
```

So far, I have tried:

```
(?<!\1\1)*(?<!\1)(.)(\1\1)*(?:\1\1)*(?!\1)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: You may use a pattern like `(.)(?<!\1{2})(?:\1\1)+(?!\1)`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3f%3c!%5c1%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3a%5c1%5c1%29%2b%28%3f!%5c1%29&i=hjasaaasjasjbbbbbashjasccccccc%0d%0aaabbccc).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That one is better. It was stupid of me to add two redundant `\1` before and after the group :-D Well, you're the king of regex, so of course it's better :-)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed It is basically the same, just a bit contracted. You may add it to your answer if you wish.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to understand why you need `(?<!\1{2})` and `(?!\1)`. wouldn't `(.)(?:\1\1)+` do the job just as well?

Comment: @GiladShnoor The point of `(?<!\1{2})` (or `(?<!\1\1)` or `(?<!\1.)` or `(?<!\1[\s\S])`, they will do the same job here) is to make sure the char before the captured one is not the same char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I didn't understand the og question. If we have the string `baaaa` we should not match anything correct?

Comment: @GiladShnoor Well, it can only be assumed that OP wants to match substrings of at least 3 char in length, and in `baaaa` the `b` is single and `aaaa` is a streak of even `a`s. No matches are expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for clarifying that. I thought that with `baaaa` OP wanted to get `aaa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a regex-only solution that matches an odd number of any character (*excluding* one-character matches):

```
(.)(?<!\1\1)\1(?:\1\1)*\1(?!\1)
```

Or a shorter version [thanks to Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew):

```
(.)(?<!\1\1)(?:\1\1)+(?!\1)
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3f%3c!%5c1%5c1%29%28%3f%3a%5c1%5c1%29%2b%28%3f!%5c1%29&i=hjasaaasjasjbbbbbashjasccccccc).**

**Breakdown:**

```
(.)         # First capturing group - matches any character.
(?<!\1\1)   # Negative lookbehind - ensures the matched char isn't preceded by the same char.
(?:\1\1)    # A non-capturing group that matches two occurrences of 
            # the same char (at least 3 in total).
+           # Matches between one and unlimited times of the previous group.
(?!\1)      # Negative lookahead to make sure no extra occurrence of the char follows.
```

**Demo in C#:**

```
string input = "hjasaaasjasjbbbbbashjasccccccc";
string pattern = @"(.)(?<!\1\1)(?:\1\1)+(?!\1)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

**Output:**

```
aaa
bbbbb
ccccccc
```

---

If you want a solution that matches an odd number of any character (*including* one-character matches):

```
(.)(?<!\1\1)(?:\1\1)*(?!\1)
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3F%3C!%5C1%5C1%29%28%3F%3A%5C1%5C1%29*%28%3F!%5C1%29&i=hjasaaasjasjbbbbbashjascccccccbbaaddd).**

Comment: is this `(?<!\1\1)` isnt preceded by the same "two" char?

Comment: Yes, but we know that the next char _is already_ preceded by one (i.e., `(.)`). We want to make sure it's not preceded by two (which means the first char in the match is not preceded by one).

Comment: Does this `(?:\1\1)` look forward or backward?

Comment: @Alex It's neither Lookbehind, nor Lookahead. This is called a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/4934172).

Comment: Also, look at [Wiktor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205729/how-to-match-an-odd-number-of-any-character-in-a-string#comment97147872_55205729) in the comments above. It's shorter than mine. I added redundant `\1` before and after the non-capturing group when I could've removed them and used `+` instead of `*` like Wiktor did.

Comment: What its used for above?

Comment: @Alex If the first matched char is `c`, then `\1(?:\1\1)*\1` means "one `c`, followed by two `c`s repeated _zero_ or more times, followed by another `c`" while `(?:\1\1)+` means "two `c`s repeated _one_ or more times" which is effectively the same thing, but in a concise way.

Comment: I believe that we don't need two `\1` inside lookbehind i.e. `(?<!\1.)` should work the same.

Comment: @revo, what does two `\1` stands for?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov Two `\1`s stand for `\1` to be used two times.