# Regex not as greedy as expected /^(\d+)[^_]/

Tags: regex, greedy

**Regex**: `/^(\d+)[^_]/gm` 
**Test String**: `12_34`

I'd expect this regex **not to match** on test string, because `\d+` is **greedy** eating the digits `1` and `2` and `[^_]` fails on `_`.

**But it unexpected matches** with only `1` in Group1. Where am I wrong?

I try to find a regular expression that matches the digits in test strings "12" or "12xx" but does not match on "12_xx"

Sample:
https://regex101.com/r/0QRTjs/1/ 
Dialect: In the end I'll use Microsoft System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: You should read about [Backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9011592/8967612) and [Atomic Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14411818/8967612). Basically, "greedy" means "as much as possible **with backtracking allowed**". The behavior that you were expecting can be achieved with an atomic group.

Comment: As to your particular example, you can just use a negative Lookahead since you probably don't need to include the character after the digits in the match: `^(\d+)(?!\d|_)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lt7Zhg/1).

Comment: OK, so the feature **Backtracking** leads to my "unexpected behaviour", because the regexp does more than I thought. And I can use **Atomic Groups** to avoid the Backtracking. `^((?>\d*))[^_]` seems to do the trick. Thank you Ahmed!

Comment: `^((?>\d*))([^_]|$)` to correctly match my digit-only line.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+` will match with one or more digits.
Since you append `[^_]`, it can only be followed by a non `_` character.
Therefore `\d+` cannot match `12` because it is followed by `_`.
`1` is the first matching group because it is followed by `2` which is not `_`.

If you want to match lines with digits only there is a very simple expression:

```
^(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d+` has the ability to reduce the number of matches if that results in an overall match. By backtracking then `2` satisfies the match of `[^_]` and `1` is captured.

See [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/NKEfAU/1)

You can use a negative lookahead at the start of the match:

```
/^(?!\d+_)(\d+)/
```

See [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/CdWQyc/1)

Or you can use an atomic group that disallows backtracking:

```
/^((?>\d+))(?:[^_]|$)/
```

See [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/WXc3BW/1)

Or use a possessive quantifier of `++` which disallows backtracking:

```
/^\d++([^_]|$)/
```

See [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/ebNkVf/1)

The possessive quantifier is likely the fastest...

Comment: `(?!=_)` is not enough and "12" will still be matched in "12_". You need `(?![_\d])`. Also, I'm guessing the `=` is a typo?

Comment: `/^((?>\d+))[^_]/` does wrong on the digit-only line. I corrected my answer in the comments. Best seems to be @41686d6564 answer `^(\d+)(?!\d|_)?`