# regex lookbehind is `>` a shortcut for `<=`?

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds

Through some convoluted testing, I ended up potentially discovering a shortcut.

A lookbehind in PowerShell is supposed to use the `<=` syntax, which is referenced in various other places when googling for lookbehinds in PowerShell, e.g., [this Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-regex-crash-course-part-4-of-5/).

Take this simple example Regex:

(?>^[^x]*)$

- (?> begins the lookbehind
- ^[^x]* tests that the character *x* is not present since the beginning of the string
- ) closes the lookbehind
- $ anchors the end of the line

When I test it:

```
'sample = x' -match '(?>^[^x]*)$'
False
```

```
'sample = ' -match '(?>^[^x]*)$'
True
```

The first block returns false: the lookbehind does not match a string without *x*.

The second block returns true: the lookbehind matches a string without *x*.

It seems to work!

Now if I try to use the `<=` syntax:

```
'sample = x' -match '(?<=^[^x]*)$'
False
```

```
'sample = ' -match '(?<=^[^x]*)$'
True
```

It has the same behavior.

Is this a "shortcut" for RegEx lookbehinds in PowerShell, or why is `>` working at all?

```
435|PS(7.2.1) C:\Users\User\Documents [230211-15:03:27]> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: This `(?>` is not a lookbehind, it denotes an [atomic group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#atomic_groups).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion with Atomic Grouping - how it differs from the Grouping in regular expression of Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411818/confusion-with-atomic-grouping-how-it-differs-from-the-grouping-in-regular-exp)

Comment: The proposed duplicate, while certainly related, isn't a duplicate per se, because it asks about atomic groups vs. regular capture groups.
This question is about atomic groups vs. lookbehind assertions; also, the regex flavor is different (Ruby vs. .NET).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Regex grouping constructs `(?<=…)` and `(?>…)` serve different purposes and only *happen to* work the same in your particular scenario; *neither* is called for in your scenario.
- Use `'...' -notmatch 'x'` to test if a given string contains any instances of `'x'` (returns `$true` if *not*).

---

**Background information**:

The two grouping constructs you reference serve different purposes (enclosed subexpressions are represented with placeholder `…` below):

- `(?<=…)` is [a (zero-width, positive) lookbehind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion):

  - It is a *non-capturing* grouping construct that must match the enclosed subexpression immediately *before* (to the left, i.e. "looking behind") where the remaining expression matches, without capturing what the subexpression matched.
  - In essence, this means: When what *follows* this construct matches, *also* make sure (assert) that what comes *before* it matches the subexpression inside `(?<=…)`; if it doesn't, there's no overall match; if it does, don't *capture* (include in the results) its match.
  - Therefore, this construct only makes sense if placed before a *capturing* construct; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Matches only 'unheard of', because only in it is the match
    # for 'hear.' preceded by 'un'
    # Captures only 'heard' from the matching string, not the 'un'
    'heard from', 'unheard of' -match '(?<=un)hear.'
    ```
- `(?>…)` is an [atomic group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#atomic_groups), aka *non-backtracking subexpression*:

  - It is a *capturing* grouping construct - similar to a [regular capture group (matched subexpression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#matched_subexpression), `(…)` - *except* that it *never backtracks*.
  - In essence, this means: once the subexpression has found a match, it won't allow backtracking based on the remainder of the expression; this construct is mostly used as a *performance optimization* when it is known that backtracking wouldn't succeed.

    ```bash
    # Atomic group:
    # -> $false, because the atomic group fully consumes the string,
    #    so there's nothing for '.' to match *after* the group.
    'abc!' -match '(?>.+).'

    # Regular capture group:
    # -> $true, with backtracking; the capture group captures 'abc'
    'abc!' -match '(.+).'
    ```

---

**What you tried**:

> `(?<=^[^x]*)$` - your regex with a *lookbehind assertion*

As noted above, there's no good reason to use a lookbehind *assertion* without following it with a *capturing* expression.
Your regex will by definition not capture anything (`$` is itself an *assertion*).

Since you're matching *the whole string*, the *immediate* simplification would be not to use a grouping construct at all (but see the bottom section):

`^[^x]*$`

As an optimization, if you explicitly want to prevent the capturing that happens by default, use a [noncapturing group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#noncapturing_group), `(?:…)`:

`(?:^[^x]*$)`

---

> `(?>^[^x]*)$` - your regex with an *atomic group*

Since you're matching the *whole string*, there is no reason to use a *atomic* group, given that there's no backtracking that needs preventing, so this regex is in effect the same as `(^[^x]*)$`, i.e. a regular capture group (followed by `$`).

As noted, there's no reason to *capture* anything here, so `(?:^[^x]*$)` would prevent that.

In short:

- Both your regexes match the input string *in full*, and therefore require no grouping construct (except, optionally, to explicitly prevent capturing).
- Read on for a much simpler solution.

---

**Taking a step back**:

The conceptually simplest and most efficient solution is:

```bash
'...' -notmatch 'x'
```

That is, you can let `-notmatch`, the negated form of PowerShell's  [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) look for (at most one) `x`, and negate the Boolean result, so that *not* finding any `x` returns `$true`.

In other words: the test succeeds if *no* `x` is present in the input string.