# Split string with regex based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split this string:

```
lg:[:after]:hover:color-blue
```

The two conditions are:

1. Split by `:`
2. If there's a `[]`, get the content (even if there's a `:` inside)

The result would be

- `lg`
- `:after`
- `hover`
- `color-blue`

Possible inputs would be:

- `[:after]:hover:color-blue`
- `hover:color-blue`
- `lg:hover:color-blue`

What I have so far:

```
const regex = /(?:([^\:\[\]]+)|\[([^\[\]]+)\])/g;

const matches = [...string.matchAll(regex)].map((match) =>
  typeof match[2] !== "undefined" ? match[2] : match[1]
);
```

It works well but the `map` feels hacky.

Is there a way to get the desired output directly from the regex?

Comment: Depending on your input you could use `split()` too, with something like [`:?\[|\]:?|:(?![^\]\[]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/uabgEi/2) though this would leave empty elements if in the input there is a colon/bracket at start or end of the string which would need to be [removed](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsMgEADAe15hT9FCzLUsFKHf0C0YMallyQa1nvJ3mwfMfH3zJeR01Kk9eqdYRRFPMdIGFvxaY0b4cIsZAhPnaaFftH4JOA5D4L0wRU28yaLLQanKGYyzp0MwJ0hzs2@HzuId1az0muj65Isv5Helev8D).

Comment: that's another approach, thanks

Comment: Is the string enclosed in brackets (`[` and `]`) always immediately preceded and followed by a colon (`:`)?

Comment: If they appear before the final `:`, yes. But I've found  a special case, e. g. `:hover-[:after]:bg-color-[primary-light]-100`... the `[primary-light]` doesn't need to be matches but the `[:after]` does.

Comment: Normally you should not substantially modify your answer after one or more answers have been posted, lest your changes invalidate those answers. In this case, however, there is only one answer and that answer has been updated to address your comment immediately above. Consequently, I suggest you edit your question to include the content of your above comment. Readers should not be required to read through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I just happened to return to this question and saw you left a reply to my question. When replying to my comment you should have begun your comment with @CarySwoveland (or just @Cary). By doing so SO would have left a message for me that a comment had been posted that was addressed to me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry, at the time of posting I was not aware that I needed a different output. I was testing a little bit and the answer provides a solution for the original question so I guess no change is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
(?<=\[)[^[\]]+(?=\])   # 1+ non-square-brackets inside a pair of those
|                      # or
(?<=^|:)               # a segment
(?:                    # that consists of multiple subsegments,
  \[[^[\]]+\]          # either bracketed
|                      # or
  [^[:\]]+             # non-bracketed,
){2,}                  # 2 or more times.
(?=:|$)                #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/imGBK3/1).

This might be shortened as `[^[\]\n]+(?=\])|(?:\[[^[\]\n]+\]|[^[:\]\n]+){2,}`, which looks less intimidating, if that happens to not match anything unexpected.

The regex above is, however, prone to backtracking. A "better" version of it would be:

```
(?<=\[)[^[\]\n]+(?=\])
|
(?<=^|:)
(?:                    # Before trying to match 2+ subsegments
  (?=([^[:\]\n]+))     # check if the next non-bracketed subsegment
  \1(?=:|$)            # is a full segment, in which case we match
|                      # and skip the 2nd alternative entirely.
  (?:
    \[[^[\]\n]+\]
  |
    [^[:\]\n]+
  ){2,}
)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/imGBK3/2).

Since ECMAScript flavor doesn't support [atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14412277), we simulated the atomic behaviour using a capturing group inside a lookahead along with the corresponding backreference.

Note that we need to use `.match()` instead of `.split()`:

```js
string.match(/[^[\]\n]+(?=\])|(?:\[[^[\]\n]+\]|[^[:\]\n]+){2,}/g)
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  'lg:[:after]:hover:color-blue',
  '[:after]:hover:color-blue',
  'hover:color-blue',
  'lg:hover:color-blue',
  'hover:[:after]:bg-color-[primary-light]-100',
  'foo:[bar]:[start-but]-not-end',
  'baz-qux:end-[but:not]:start'
];

const regex = /[^[\]\n]+(?=\])|(?:\[[^[\]\n]+\]|[^[:\]\n]+){2,}/g;

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(testcase, testcase.match(regex));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Or... you can just split by [`(?<!\[[^[\]]*):`](https://regex101.com/r/imGBK3/3) and handle things from there; that would be the "shortest" and clearest solution:

```js
string.split(/(?<!\[[^[\]]*):/).map(
  token => token.match(/^\[.+]$/) ? token.slice(1, -1) : token
)
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  'lg:[:after]:hover:color-blue',
  '[:after]:hover:color-blue',
  'hover:color-blue',
  'lg:hover:color-blue',
  'hover:[:after]:bg-color-[primary-light]-100',
  'foo:[bar]:[start-but]-not-end',
  'baz-qux:end-[but:not]:start'
];

const regex = /(?<!\[[^[\]]*):/;

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(
    testcase,
    testcase.split(regex).map(
      token => token.match(/^\[.+]$/) ? token.slice(1, -1) : token
    )
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, I've found a special case, e. g. : `hover:[:after]:bg-color-[primary-light]-100`... `[primary-light]` doesn't need to be matched but `[:after]` does.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. After posting the question, I discovered that I need to know if the "modifier" comes from a `[]` or not, so the `split` will work better in that case. But it's good to have a solution for the OQ. Thanks!