# Restricting character length in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am using the following regular expression without restricting any character length:

```
var test =  /^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\""\']*$/ // Works fine
```

In the above when I am trying to restrict the characters length to 15 as below, it throws an error.

```
var test =  /^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\""\']*${1,15}/    //**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression**
```

How can I make the above regular expression work with the characters limit to 15?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both C# and JavaScript?

Comment: For .NET, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76822352) of mine at a similar question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot apply quantifiers to anchors. Instead, **to restrict the length of the input string**, use a lookahead anchored at the beginning:

```
// ECMAScript (JavaScript, C++)
^(?=.{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*$
^^^^^^^^^^^

// Or, in flavors other than ECMAScript and Python
\A(?=.{1,15}\z)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*\z
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// Or, in Python
\A(?=.{1,15}\Z)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*\Z
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, I assume you wanted to match 0 or more letters or digits with `(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*`. It should look like `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` (i.e. use a character class here).

**Why not use a limiting quantifier, like `{1,15}`, at the end?**

Quantifiers are only applied to the subpattern to the left, be it a group or a character class, or a literal symbol. Thus, `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']{1,15}$` will effectively restrict the length of the second character class `[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']` to 1 to 15 characters. The `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*){1,15}$` will "restrict" the sequence of 2 subpatterns of unlimited length (as the `*` (and `+`, too) can match unlimited number of characters) to 1 to 15 times, and we still do not restrict the length of the *whole input string*.

**How does the lookahead restriction work?**

The `(?=.{1,15}$)` / `(?=.{1,15}\z)` / `(?=.{1,15}\Z)` [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) appears right after `^`/`\A` (note in Ruby, `\A` is the only anchor that matches only start of the whole string) start-of-string [**anchor**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). It is a *zero-width assertion* that only returns true or false after checking if its subpattern matches the subsequent characters. So, this lookahead tries to match any 1 to 15 (due to the [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,15}`) characters but a newline right at the end of the string (due to the `$`/`\z`/`\Z` anchor). If we remove the `$` / `\z` / `\Z` anchor from the lookahead, the lookahead will only require the string to *contain* 1 to 15 characters, but the total string length can be any.

If the input string can contain a newline sequence, you should use `[\s\S]` portable any-character regex construct (it will work in JS and other common regex flavors):

```
// ECMAScript (JavaScript, C++)
^(?=[\s\S]{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// Or, in flavors other than ECMAScript and Python
\A(?=[\s\S]{1,15}\z)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*\z
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// Or, in Python
\A(?=[\s\S]{1,15}\Z)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\"']*\Z
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Not really sure you need this regex. It will match 0 or more letters or digits, and then 0 or more characters other than the ones in the `$%^&*;:,<>?()"'` set. Please clarify what strings are valid (you want to match) and those that are not.

Comment: If you have newline symbols in your string, replace the first look-ahead with `(?=[\s\S]{1,15}$)`.

Comment: In C# the above one won't work when trying to assign the regEx to a string . Do i need to do this ^(?=.{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\""']*$

Comment: It will work if you use a normal string literal. With verbatim string literal, it will look like `var rx = new Regex(@"^(?=.{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()""']*$")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I've read [this article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) about using solely lookaheads for validation (not only about string length) like this: `\A(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})(?=\D*\d)\w{6,10}\z` - what do you think about such approach?

Comment: @Maximus The principle of contrast is a proper way to go in your pattern. It is not about restricting the input string length though, it is a specific validation issue. This regex will not work in JS, BTW.