# Lookahead (?=pattern) without preceding pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I learned that the lookahead regex is like this `x(?=y)` and means

> Matches x only if x is followed by y.

according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). However I find this code on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern3):

```
<p>A form with a password field that must contain 8 or more characters that are of at least one number, and one uppercase and lowercase letter:</p>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
Password: <input type="password" name="pw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Why does (?=.*\d) indicate "at least one number appears in the string"? And the three pair of parentheses don't matter where the match is, because as I look at this, it should be first one or more digit followed by one or more lowercase letters and then one or more uppercase letters and then 8 or more characters, what is wrong?

After a little search, it seems regex is different in various languages, is that what this is about?

**edit:**
I don't think you guys got my question. I meant the lookahead is like x(?=y), but the (?=.*\d) doesn't precede with anything, so what to match? And the second question, the three parentheses comes with specific order, but the match doesn't have to be same order, since /abc/ matches "abcdd" not "cbdda" ---- why doesn't the order matter?

**update:**
OK, probably I have a misunderstanding of lookahead, and thanks to whoever changed my title for this problem. So here's my final update if there's no more need after:

My problem is like the title says, a lookahead (?=pattern) can omit the preceding pattern, so what does it mean when nothing before the parentheses? I searched for 'lookahead', almost all explanation comes with a preceding pattern.

And I tried something on regex tester:
/(?=\d)/ will create an infinite match if the string contains a digit, like "a2", but it will show "no match" if the string has no digit, like "a"

Interestingly /(?=\d)./ will match for any digit, now it seems equals to \d

I have no idea what's going on right now, I'll go and learn the lookahead again but any further answers are welcomed, thanks

Comment: "why doesn't the order matter" -- because a look ahead does not consume the input. That's basically the gist of my answer …

Comment: @Drake: `*` matches zero or more characters other than a newline as many as possible. Thus, the `(?=.*<SOMEPATTERN>)` lookahead just checks if there is <SOMEPATTERN> somewhere  further on the current line. If there is that pattern, "true" if returned, the engine searches further or returns a valid match. Is that clear?

Comment: The `pattern` attribute value is *anchored* by default, `^(?:` is added at the beginning, and `)$` is added at the end. Thus, the lookaheads actually are executed one by one after the start position was matched. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477182/restricting-character-length-in-regular-expression/32477224#32477224) on how such lookaheads work.

Comment: [One more explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): *The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then **gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match**. That is why they are called **"assertions"**. They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.*.

Comment: *what does it mean when nothing before the parentheses?* - Wrong, there are *empty string locations* before each character in a string. An unanchored lookahead will be executed (the lookahead subpattern will try to match the string with its subpattern) at every such location (in `abc`, `(?=\w)` will match 3 empty strings: before `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: *And I tried something on regex tester: /(?=\d)/ will create an infinite match if the string contains a digit* is only true if you use a global modifier `/g`. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830/3832970) how to override this behavior.

Comment: */(?=\d)./ will match for any digit, now it seems equals to \d* - yes, in meaning, but not in how it is done internally. The lookahead does double work before matching the digit with `.`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much for detailed explanation, I read the post from regular-expressions.info and I did got some clue from the line you quoted. I have to sleep now, hope my mind would be clearer tomorrow, thanks again, good night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *(?=pattern)* is a [regex lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It's a zero-width, "true or false" part of the pattern that doesn't actually "eat" any characters, but must match (be true) for the expression to succeed. So,

```
(?=.*\d)
```

means "lookahead to see `.*\d`, which is 'anything' (any number of times, greedy), followed by a number". Since the `.*` will by default eat up all characters until the end of the string, obviously the `\d` wouldn't have anything left to eat for itself. The `.*` backtracks, or gives up, a character at a time until the `\d` can match. Since `*` means 'zero or more', `.*` will give up everything it has matched, if necessary, to let the `\d` match. Thus, at least *one digit somewhere in the string* is enough to let the pattern match.