# Regular expression to match following criterias

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate  input (number with decimal optional) in c# with regular expression with following conditions

1. Max length of should be 4
2. only positive numbers
3. decimal is optional
   Eg valid case :

  1

  12

  123

  1234

  1.23

  12.3

  0

Invalid cases :

1. All -ive numbers
2. Length exceeds 4 including decimal(.)

I have created following expression which is working fine but only problem is I am not able to restrict it to 4 max length

here is my regular expression :

```
^[\+]?(([0-9]+)([\.,]([0-9]+))?|([\.,]([0-9]+))?)$
```

Comment: [Here is how it is done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477182/restricting-character-length-in-regular-expression).

Comment: `(?=^[\d\.]{1,4}$)`..

Comment: A very good tool with "cheatsheet" for testing regular expressions - http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, it won't because of other conditions already present in OP's regex.. check:- https://regex101.com/r/rJ0dX7/1

Comment: @rock321987 your regexp also matches `"."` which is clearly not intended. Or `"1..2"` which is not a number either, or `"1.2."`

Comment: @derpirscher please check it..see here :- https://regex101.com/r/rJ0dX7/2..

i think you all are considering my comment as final regex..it needs to be added in OP's regex..my bad..i should have added it

Comment: @rock321987 you should have pointed that out and given the final result that works.

Comment: I guess [`^(?=[+]?.{1,4}$)(?:[+]?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?|([.,][0-9]+)?))$`](https://regex101.com/r/gT3rB1/1) should work (if the `+` is not to be counted in). Surely, the regex can be further improved, but it is not what the question is about.