# Regex pattern for string having spaces only at end

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a requirement where I need to match string which satisfies all of the below requirements -

1. String must be of length 12
2. String can have only following characters - Alphabets, Digits and Spaces
3. Spaces if any must be at the end of the string. Spaces in between are not allowed.

I have tried with below regex -

```
"^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]{12}$"
```

Above regex is satisfying requirement #1 and #2 but not able to satisfy #3.
Please help me to achieve the requirements.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?=.{12}$)[0-9a-zA-Z]*\s*$
```

If at least one letter must exist:

```py
^(?=.{12}$)[0-9a-zA-Z]+\s*$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{12}$)` - the string must contain 12 chars
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more alphanumeroics
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PDVx9i/2).

Comment: This is working to match, what about a solution that enables searching?

Comment: @mozway This comment is irrelevant to the current requirements. The OP question is about validation and not extraction from longer text.

Comment: Thus my question, I am curious if you had an answer to that ;)

Comment: @mozway Then please go ahead and post it. I do not know your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks..it solved my problem. But can you please explain me (?=.{12}$) how this is working ?

Comment: @SurajPandey See [Restricting Character length in Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32477224/3832970). It is a positive lookahead, it just checks if its pattern can eb matched immediately on the right. If it matches, matching can proceed, else, the match is failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [non-word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\B`:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|\s\B){12}$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZKLau/1)

With it, a space can't be followed by a letter or a digit, but only by a non-word character (a space here) or the end of the string.

To ensure at least one character that isn't blank:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|\s\B){11}$
```

Note that with PCRE you have to use the D (DOLLAR END ONLY) modifier to be sure that `$` matches the end of the string and not before the last newline sequence. Or better replace `$` with `\z`. There isn't this kind of problem with Python and the re module.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?!.*\h\S)[\da-zA-Z\h]{12}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQl9ti/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\h\S)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if a whitespace is followed by a non-whitespace character
- `[\da-zA-Z\h]{12}`: Match 12 characters of alphanumerics or white space
- `$`: End