# Pandas str.extract() to limit number of alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a pandas dataframe of descriptions like this:

```
df['description']

22CI003294 PARCEL 32 
22CI400040 NORFOLK ESTATES 
12CI400952 & 13CI403261
22CI400628 GARDEN ACRES
9CI00208 FERNHAVEN SEC
22CI400675 CECIL AVE SUB
22CI400721 124.69' SS
BOLLING AVE SS
```

I want to extract the first alphanumeric characters that are at least 6 characters in length. They have to start with a digit and then can repeat any amount of digit or letters. So, expected results from above:

```
22CI003294
22CI400040
12CI400952
22CI400628
9CI00208
22CI400675
22CI400721
None
```

What I have tried:

```
df['results'] = df['description'].str.extract(r'(\d*\w+\d+\w*){6,}')
```

When I added in `{6,}` at the end I suddenly get no matches. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe you need `^([^\W_]{6,})`? Or, `^(?=[^\W\d_]*\d)[^\W_]{6,}`? Or even `^(?=\d*[^\W\d_])(?=[^\W\d_]*\d)[^\W_]{6,}`?

Comment: I just need to filter out by character numbers once it's matched. Why doesn't my regex work after I added in `{6,}`?

Comment: It makes no sense here, you quantified the whole sequence and using it with `str.extract`, you just would have extracted the last capture.

Comment: So, what is that you are after? Extract the alphanumeric string with at least one digit and at least one letter at the start of string if there are 6 or more chars?

Comment: Basically, `^([^\W_]{6,})` as you suggested will work. I want to extract any alphanumeric characters that are greater than 6 characters. My regex of `(\d*\w+\d+\w*)` matches the numbers just fine. But I have no idea why I couldn't add `{6,}` at the end to limit character number.

Comment: And yes they have to start with a digit and then can repeat any amount of digit or letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to limit the character length is not correct, see why at [Restricting character length in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32477224/3832970).

You can use

```py
df['results'] = df['description'].str.extract(r'^(\d[^\W_]{5,})')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/podibe/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d[^\W_]{5,})` - Group 1:

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[^\W_]{5,}` - five or more letters or digits.

If the match is not always expected at the start of string, replace the `^` anchor with the numeric (`(?<!\d)`) or a word (`\b`) boundary.

Comment: I added an additional example at the end so that it won't match pure letter words.

Comment: @amnesic Yes, `^(\d[^\W_]{5,})`, `(?<!\d)(\d[^\W_]{5,})` and `\b(\d[^\W_]{5,})` do not match `BOLLING AVE SS`. The current solution still stands.