# Why does this regex match a string that is greater than 10 of the desired characters?

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I have the following regular expression and I am using https://www.regextester.com/ to test it.

```
^(?=^.{10})[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+\s*
```

The requirement is that the input could be alpha characters and numbers separated by a colon with some trailing whitespace.  The input must start with the alpha characters but could have superfluous characters after the trailing whitespace or the last number that I don't want to match after the 10th.  The string to match must be exactly 10 characters.  In the following example strings I have emboldened what I thought would match. I am not anchoring with a $ at the end because I know that the input string in question will likely have more than 10 characters so I am not trying to check that the entire string matches.

**A:12345678**  // matches which is fine

**A:12345678**9 // Should only match up to the 8

**FOO:567890**s123 // should only match up to the 0

The actual result is that it is matching everything after the 10th character too so long as it is an alphanumeric or whitespace. I expect it to match up to the 10th character and nothing more.  How do I fix this expression?

Update: I will eventually try to incorporated this regex into a C++ program using a boost regex to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If supported, you can use a lookbehind with a finite quantifier asserting 10 chars to the left at the end of the pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+(?<=^.{10})
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z followed by `:` and 1+ digits
- `(?<=^.{10})` Positive lookbehind, assert that from the current position there are 10 characters to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RpbMYa/1)

If you want to match trailing whitespace chars:

```
^[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\s*(?<=^.{10})
```

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline.

Comment: This one appears to be the best answer so far. I didn't think a look behind would work, but it seems to match according to my expectations. I'm still experimenting with it to study it with some additional input strings.

Comment: Ok.  Just one update needed to the answer.  you forgot the allowable trailing spaces.  "^[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\s*(?<=^.{10})" is what I used that worked.

Comment: @shawn1874 If you also want to match the trailing spaces,  then that adjusted pattern works. Note that `\s*` matches whitespace chars, which could also match a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`(?=^.{10})` is ensuring that the string has at least 10 characters, but nothing more.

To ensure that the first 10 characters match the main expression, you still need an anchor. It must be more than just `$`, however:

```
^                  # At the start of the string
(?=.{10}(.*))      # lookahead to 10 characters and capture the rest of the line
[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+   # then try to match the main expression
(?=                # before ensuring that what follows it
  \h*\1$           # is the same group 1 preceded by some horizontal whitespaces, if any.
)                  #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iLYqE3/2).

Note that the expression above also trim trailing spaces if the main part is shorter than 10 characters. If you do want to include trailing spaces in your match, move `\h*` outside of the second lookahead:

```
^(?=.{10}(.*))[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\h*(?=\1$)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iLYqE3/3).

This trick is partly covered by [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889546) at another question.

Comment: In your [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iLYqE3/2) you have `\h*` instead of `\s*`. Regardless, it causes you to match `LOREM:42`, which is not 10 characters long, a requirement. And I don't believe that the 10-character requirement can include trailing whitespace. If it did then you would just use `^(?=.{10}(.*))[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\s*(?=\1$)`

Comment: I don't understand why you're capturing the text after the matched text.

Comment: I agree that this one is close and does match the 10 characters as needed but then it keeps matching additional whitespace as a separate group.  It's not quite what I needed, but still a useful regex to explore and study.

Comment: @Booboo `\h` is for demo only; OP didn't specify the flavor at the time I answered so I used `\s` which is more widely implemented. Regarding the 10-character limit, you are correct: I misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: @Reilas It's for creating our own "anchor". `(.*)` inside a lookahead is atomic once it matched and therefore only `[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\h*` in `[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\h*\1$` (or `[A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+\h*(?=\1$)`, for that matter) can backtrack.

Comment: The capturing group is a side effect. If you don't want capturing groups at all, @Thefourthbird's answer will be more suitable.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... The ... input could be alpha characters and numbers separated by a colon ... [and] must start with the alpha characters ... The string to match must be exactly 10 characters. ..."*

You can utilize multiple constructs to help narrow the matches.

```
^(?=[A-Z]{1,8}:\d{1,8}\d)[^:]+:\d+?(?<=[A-Z].{9})
```

Here is a break-down.

- Use a *look-ahead* to assert the values and order of values

  ```java
  ^(?=[A-Z]{1,8}:\d{1,8}\d)
  ```
- Define a pattern

  ```java
  [^:]+:\d+?
  ```
- Finalize the conditions with a *look-behind*, to assert the starting value, hence total match length

  ```
  (?<=[A-Z].{9})
  ```

I'm unsure what *regex engine* you're using, here is an example using *JavaScript*.

```js
var a = ['A:12345678', 'A:123456789', 'FOO:567890s123']
var p = /(?=[A-Z]{1,8}:\d{1,8}\d)[^:]+:\d+?(?<=[A-Z].{9})/g
a.forEach(x => console.log(x.match(p)));
```

Comment: Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WYBpEb/1) for your proposed solution. Note that this can match far more than 10 characters. And the OP is not interested in matching anywhere other than the start of string.

Comment: @Booboo, I've updated my answer, I'm sure this will resolve it correctly.

Comment: `\d{1,8}\d` is the same as `\d{2, 9}` and both require a minimum of 2 digits in an exception string. So it will not match  **AAAAAAAA:1**. Also, you need to accept lower-case alpha characters.

Comment: Agree with booboo.  Also I can't constrain either the alpha characters or numbers.  Either set of characters to the left and right of the colon must be constrained only with a 1 or more syntax so that I have flexibility.